# silverlight child window

Tags: silverlight, childwindow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [silverLight childWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744666/silverlight-childwindow)

how can i do that my child window will be always on top? now its being blocked by other windows...

Comment: Are you using the actual ChildWindow, or some other popup style window?

Comment: The title for your question is really bad and exact duplicate of your other question. 

Also what do you mean by "blocked by other windows"? Other childwindows? Other browser windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i talked to someone who works in microsoft, and he told me that this is a bug when combines html and silverlight. so there is no way to solve this now...

Answer (score 1):

Check the z-axis