# silverLight childWindow

Tags: silverlight, childwindow

how can i do my childWindow to be always on top?

Comment: Show the code you are using to display the "childwindow".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by ChildWindows you mean the ChildWindow object in Silverlight then it should always appear on top, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.childwindow%28VS.95%29.aspx) says:

> A ChildWindow always displays in a
>   modal popup that blocks user
>   interaction with the underlying user
>   interface.

But if by ChildWindow you mean something else you created in Silverlight then you need to set the [ZIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.zindex%28VS.95%29.aspx) property of that object to a very big number:

> The z-order of an object determines
>   whether the object is in front of or
>   behind another overlapping object. By
>   default, the z-order of objects within
>   a Panel  is determined by the sequence
>   in which they are declared. Objects
>   that are declared later appear in
>   front of objects that are declared
>   earlier. You can change this behavior
>   by setting the Canvas..::.ZIndex
>   attached property on objects within
>   the Panel. Higher values are closer to
>   the foreground; lower values are
>   farther from the foreground.

In codebehind you would write:

```
myObject.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 100);
```

and in XAML you would need to write

```
<Rectangle Canvas.ZIndex="100" />
```

Comment: and how can i get teh Z-order?

Comment: Was my answer helpful or do you need any more assistance? If not maybe you could mark my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Popup control will help you?
http://jesseliberty.com//2008/06/06/popup-control/